# call web method from code behind

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0

I need to call a `webmethod of a webservice` with Jquery but I have defined web method on `webservice.asmx` page .But now I need to write that page on my default.aspx.cs page and this is not working when I am calling it from jquery ajax...

I have

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $contentLoadTriggered = false;
        $(window).scroll(
    function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

            $contentLoadTriggered = true;

            $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "DynamicDataLoad2.aspx/GetDataFromServer",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#wrapperDiv").append(msg.d);
            $contentLoadTriggered = false;
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert("The call to the server side failed. ");
        }
    });
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

and I have defined GetDataFromServer() on Default.aspx.cs page.

Comment: please post some related code from your default.aspx

Comment: I am sure there can be bigger explanation than 'its not working'

Comment: this is the whole jquery function that I am using and it is working fine if I call this method from .asmx file

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
 url : "AppUrl/<WebMethod>",
 type : "GET",
 success : function(data){
  }
});
```

Try this

Comment: That is the standard way to call. Use firebug and tell me what exactly are you getting. Is the request been passed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but I need to call this method from same .cs page and this syntax is not working.

Comment: from same CS page but you want to use jQuery?? :O :O :O

Comment: I am working on asp.net project and I have a Default.aspx page and a Default.aspx.cs page associated to that Default.aspx.